# Configure SQL server reportign service to send email

Tags: email, sql-server-2005, ssrs

I'm configuring SQL server 2005 reporting server to send emails outside the domain. I have followed the steps outlined at [MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972234%28SQL.80%29.aspx) but have a question:

How can I supply a domain user to connect to the Exchange server in the same domain? I've tried

```
<SMTPAccountName>DOMAIN\User</SMTPAccountName>
```

in the rsreportserver.config.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can find the answer here:
http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1453

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familar with how SQL Server 2005 interacts with SMTP, but for other apps they expect the mail account to be in smtp (email) format rather than LANMAN format.

If you've got a working AD tree this should be user@yourdomain.co.uk, failing that try using user@domain.